# How to get substring with specific ranges in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, substring, swift4

This is using the example code from the official Swift4 doc

```
let greeting = "Hi there! It's nice to meet you! "
let endOfSentence = greeting.index(of: "!")!
let firstSentence = greeting[...endOfSentence]
// firstSentence == "Hi there!"
```

But lets say `let greeting = "Hello there world!"`
 and I want to **retrieve only the second word** (substring) in this sentence? So I only want the word "there".

I've tried using "world!" as an argument like 
`let endOfSentence = greeting.index(of: "world!")!` but Swift 4 Playground doesn't like that. It's expecting 'Character' and my argument is a string.

So how can I get a substring of a very precise subrange? Or get nth word in a sentence for greater use in the future?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can search for substrings using `range(of:)`.

```
import Foundation

let greeting = "Hello there world!"

if let endIndex = greeting.range(of: "world!")?.lowerBound {
    print(greeting[..<endIndex])
}
```

outputs:

```
Hello there
```

EDIT:

If you want to separate out the words, there's a quick-and-dirty way and a good way. The quick-and-dirty way:

```
import Foundation

let greeting = "Hello there world!"

let words = greeting.split(separator: " ")

print(words[1])
```

And here's the thorough way, which will enumerate all the words in the string no matter how they're separated:

```
import Foundation

let greeting = "Hello there world!"

var words: [String] = []

greeting.enumerateSubstrings(in: greeting.startIndex..<greeting.endIndex, options: .byWords) { substring, _, _, _ in
    if let substring = substring {
        words.append(substring)
    }
}

print(words[1])
```

EDIT 2: And if you're just trying to get the 7th through the 11th character, you can do this:

```
import Foundation

let greeting = "Hello there world!"

let startIndex = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
let endIndex = greeting.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5)

print(greeting[startIndex..<endIndex])
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have been more clear. I want precisely the word "There". From a Java background, I would just shove the string into a string array and print from the indices 7 to 11. Is there no built in way in Swift4 using the substring members?

Comment: @KentW Try that on for size.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to import foundation. Thorough answer. I couldn't find this in the Swift 4 iBook.

Comment: I just want to know what make swift to get substring so complicated compared with other languages.

Answer (score 18):

For swift4,

```
let string = "substring test"
let start = String.Index(encodedOffset: 0)
let end = String.Index(encodedOffset: 10)
let substring = String(string[start..<end])
```

Comment: Note that if the string contains characters that require more than one UTF-16 code unit (like emojis), `String.Index(encodedOffset:)` may get you something different from what you expect.

Comment: The use of `encodedOffset` is [considered harmful](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/#use-of-stringindexencodedoffset-considered-harmful) and will be [deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0241-string-index-explicit-encoding-offset.md).

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 5 encodedOffset (swift 4 func) is deprecated.
You will need to use [utf160Offset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/index/3151848-init)

```
// Swift 5     

let string = "Hi there! It's nice to meet you!"
let startIndex = 10 // random for this example
let endIndex = string.count

let start = String.Index(utf16Offset: startIndex, in: string)
let end = String.Index(utf16Offset: endIndex, in: string)

let substring = String(string[start..<end])
```

prints -> It's nice to meet you!

Answer (score 4):

There is one mistake in the first answer.

```
Range<String.Index>.upperBound
```

The upperBound property should be the endIndex
For Example:

```
let text = "From Here Hello World"
if let result = text.range(of: "Hello World") {
     let startIndex = result.upperBound
     let endIndex = result.lowerBound
     print(String(text[startIndex..<endIndex])) //"Hello World"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the simplest way I use is :

```
var str = "abcdefg"
String(Array(str)[2...4])
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for in my use case thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old habits die hard. I did it the "Java" way and split the string up by spaces, then accessed the second word.

```
print(greeting.split(separator: " ")[1]) // "there /n"
```